# How to evaluate the sum using values from the data being input

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a problem in evaluating a sum using values from data I input.

Suppose I have `data = {1, 3, 5, 6, 8}`

If I want to evaluate the sum of my data (1+3+5+6+8), I can use the following command:

```
Sum[x, {x, data}]
```

And it will give me 23, which is correct.

However, I found difficulty if I want to evaluate the sum of Log of each value, such that I have: Log(1) + Log(3) + Log(5) + Log(6) + Log(8). This can be done manually if I type the function one by one, but then it is not efficient if I have 100 values to be calculated. 
Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Something like `Total[Log[data]]`?

Comment: and if you want to stick to your strategy `Sum[x,{x,Log[data]}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sum it's much better to use [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Total.html)

```
Total@data
(*23*)
```

for the Logs, you can use the fact that `Log` is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html?q=Listable&lang=en) and write

```
Total@Log@data
(*Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[6] + Log[8]*)
```

(if you need a numerical value just use `N`)

Answer (score 3):

You can still you `Sum`, but you are now summing $\sum_{x \in \text{data}}\log(x)$ rather than $\sum_{x \in \text{data}}x$:

```
In[367]:= data = {1, 3, 5, 6, 8};
Sum[Log[x], {x, data}]

Out[368]= Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[6] + Log[8]

In[369]:= Total[Log[data]]

Out[369]= Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[6] + Log[8]
```

Comment: Sasha, you're back!  I hope you stay around this time. :-)